# nmake equivalent of mingw command

Tags: c, webkit, mingw, linker-errors, cl

I am giving it a shot at compiling the library at https://github.com/zserge/webview using Windows Build tools.

The command line for `mingw` is

```
cc main.c -DWEBVIEW_WINAPI=1 -lole32 -lcomctl32 -loleaut32 -luuid -mwindows -o webview-example.exe
```

I am using `/D WEBVIEW_WINAPI=1` and the .h file is successfully compiled.  But it fails at link with `unresolved externals`.  I am not sure what to use for `-lole32` etc.

I tried `/L` but it gives error. Any idea what is the equivalent?

**EDIT:**

I added `/link ole32.lib comctl32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib` as linker flags, but still gives error at link:

```
C:\Users\Arun\webview>cl main.c /D WEBVIEW_WINAPI=1 /link ole32.lib comctl32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
c:\users\arun\webview\webview.h(1155): warning C4477: 'sscanf' : format string '%02x' requires an argument of type 'unsigned int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'char *'
c:\users\arun\webview\webview.h(1155): note: consider using '%hhx' in the format string
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27027.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
ole32.lib
comctl32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
main.obj
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateSolidBrush referenced in function webview_set_color
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegCloseKey referenced in function webview_fix_ie_compat_mode
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegCreateKeyA referenced in function webview_fix_ie_compat_mode
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegSetValueExA referenced in function webview_fix_ie_compat_mode
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following command:

```
cl main.c /D WEBVIEW_WINAPI=1 /link ole32.lib comctl32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib gdi32.lib advapi32.lib
```

The missing functions were residing at gdi32.lib and advapi32.lib.

Thanks